# What should I install for react and babel?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, babeljs, npm-install

Trying to install react with Babel. What is the difference between all of these installs? Which ones should I choose?

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
npm install --save-dev babel-cli
npm install --save-dev babel-core
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-env
```

EDIT:

I'm working from this tutorial:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html

which says to install babel-preset-react and babel-preset-es2015, but when I go to https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/, or any other site, everyone has a different idea of what to install.

Comment: This question could use a lot more detail about why you're installing these, if you're working from a tutorial, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing, but most likely you're working from a React tutorial and wondering what you're installing. You can look up each of these modules on [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/), the web frontend for npm repository.

Babel is ECMAScript2015 (aka: ES6) pre-processor that converts ES6-style javascript to ES5-style so that it can be run in browsers that don't support all the ES6 features yet. Features such as module importing, arrow functions, generators, etc. It is most likely part of a webpack build which, among other things, will expand your react jsx templates inside your components as well as "babelify" your source.

React generally encourages modular design using ES6 so it's necessary to follow their patterns and still have the code run reliably in browsers.